# How to loop two objects in one table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data like this one but find hard to loop both objects and get data into one table where th to be company and td to be their drivers

```
{…}
  driver: Array(18) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
  company: "TEST"
{…}
  driver: Array(10) [ {…}, {…} ]
  company: "TEST 1"
```

​
i tried like this one but is do not work properly

```
            $.each(response.allDrivers, function(key, value){

          var thead = '';
          thead += '<th>'+value.company+'</th>';

          $('#table-allDrivers thead tr').append(thead);

          $.each(value.driver, function(id,name){
            var tbody = '';
            tbody = '<tr> <td>'+name.driver+'<td></tr>';
            $('#table-allDrivers tbody').append(tbody);
          })
        });
```

result im getting is like this one

```
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>TEST</th>
  <th>TEST 1</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td>Driver 1</td>
   <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Driver 2</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Driver 3</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Driver 4</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little different from how you have it there, but you can try something like this—run the snippet to see the result:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    driver: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
    company: "Company1"
  },
  {
    driver: ['item1', 'item2'],
    company: "Company2"
  }
]

var thead = document.querySelector('table thead tr')
var tbody = document.querySelector('table tbody')

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  thead.innerHTML += '<th>' + item.company + '</th>';
  
  item.driver.forEach(function(driverItem) {
    tbody.innerHTML += '<tr></tr>';
  })
  tbody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(function(tr, i) {
    tr.innerHTML += item.driver[i] ? '<td>' + item.driver[i] + '</td>' : '<td></td>' //catering for colspan layout
    tr.innerHTML === '<td></td>' ? tr.remove() : '' //removing empty <tr> elements
  })
})
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey @Ivan , I improved the answer a little. Just added 2 things to cater for `<td>` colspans and to remove empty `<tr>` elements =)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 2 driver (driver1 and driver2) but maybe more. Find the one with more elements and iterate from that (I assumed driver1 has more elements);

```
var markup = "";
for( let i = 0 ; i < driver1.length; i++)
{
if (i < driver2.length)
{
markup += '<tr><td>'+driver1[i].+'</td><td>'+driver2[i]+'</td><tr>';
}
else
{
markup += '<tr><td>'+driver1[i].+'</td><td></td><tr>';
}

}

  $('#table-allDrivers tbody').append(markup);
```

I think this would show the correct result even if this is not the best way but i tried with as much information i got.

Comment: what this should mean ? var driver2Length = var driver2.length;

Comment: i fixed some characters i was trying to explain differently thats why  i forgot to modify some lines. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

The right way to use HTML Tables with multiple values for each cell is to use `rowspan` or `colspan` attribute, which in your case each company has multiple drivers. To achieve that:

Javascript:

```
// Your data
const allDrivers = [
    {
        drivers: ['driverComapnyA-1', 'driverComapnyA-2', 'driverComapnyA-3'],
        company: 'Comapny A',
    },
    {
        drivers: [
            'driverComapanyB-1',
            'driverComapanyB-2',
            'driverComapanyB-3',
            'driverComapanyB-4',
        ],
        company: 'Comapny B',
    },
];

allDrivers.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (index == 0) {
        // Make sure to setup tbody markup once
        $('#table-allDrivers').append('<tbody></tbody>');
    }

    const tableBody = $('#table-allDrivers').find('tbody');

    tableBody.append(
        '<tr data-index="' +
            index +
            '"><th rowspan="' +
            item.drivers.length +
            '">' +
            item.company +
            '</th></tr>'
    );

    item.drivers.forEach((driver, i) => {
        if (i == 0) {
            // if its the first item in drivers array then add it as a child in <tr>
            tableBody
                .find('[data-index="' + index + '"')
                .append('<td>' + driver + '</td>');
        } else {
            // otherwise just append it to <tbody>
            tableBody.append('<tr><td>' + driver + '</td></tr>')
        }
    });
});
```

Markup:

```
<table id="table-allDrivers"></table>
```

And here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khzway7u/